# MySql (Hibernate) Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I got problem with write the query, i got 3 tables

Lake
-id

Peg
-id
-peg_name
-peg_number
-lake_id

Reservation
-id
-peg_id

I need know reservation for single lake. Anybody can help me with that ?

Comment: Please add table description,some insert datas and your expected result

Comment: select 

reservation.user_id,reservation.start_day,reservation.end_day,lake.id,peg.id,peg.peg_number from reservation 

left join peg ON reservation.peg_id = peg.id

left join lake ON peg.lake_id = lake.id

where lake.id = :lakeId;  

This query is working on workbench, but dont want work in application (hibernate )

Comment: Kindly add table description in the question post as describing them in comment section is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Try use ten nativeQuery, and return one entity for query use they to take the data which you need.

For this query you can return value in this way because you return class not few value. Is possible to return array object, or try use projection.